# How to use environment variables in Visual Studio Debug Command

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, environment-variables, visual-studio-2019

I'm attempting to launch Python from its default Windows 10 installer location for a C++ Python library project.

This works:

```
C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

This does not:

```
%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

However %LocalAppData% seems to work in other parts of the project config to search for headers and libs etc.  If I "Run" the string %LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe in Explorer it will execute Python.exe correctly so the path is correct.

Can you use Environment Variables in the Configuration Properties >> Debugging >> Command field in VS 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK just found a solution.  There's a $(LOCALAPPDATA) macro so this works:

```
$(LOCALAPPDATA)\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```